# Set text format to 'full_html' for each value of a multi-value text field

Tags: php

I have an unlimited **formatted text field** and I am trying to programmatically set the **text format** of every value to `full_html`.

**I have tried:**

```
$Links = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$node->field_article_links[] = $Links;
$node->field_article_links->format = 'full_html';
$node->save();
```

and

```
$Links = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach ($Links as $Link) {
$node->set('field_article_links', $Link);
$node->field_article_links->format = 'full_html';
}
$node->save();
```

But the results are always the same, only the format of the first value of the field is set to 'full_html' and the others remain unchanged.

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working as expected:

```
$links = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);    
$field_data = [];
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $element = [];
    $element['value'] = $link;
    if($link === 3) {
        $element['format'] = 'full_html';
    } else {
        $element['format'] = 'dasdas';
    }
    $field_data[] = $element;
}
$node->field_article_links = $field_data;
$node->save();
```